# Unable to remove OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy from CsOnlineUser in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, skype-for-business, microsoft-teams

In PowerShell after having added a VoiceRoutingPolicy to a CsOnlineUser, I have not been able to remove it again afterwards, this prevents me from deleting the VoiceRoutingPolicy.

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/grant-csvoiceroutingpolicy?view=skype-ps#examples), I need to use `Grant-CsVoiceRoutingPolicy` and simply grant a `$Null` policy to the user. I have attempted this as follow, unfortunately without success:

```
PS C:\Users\jkj> Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity bruger2@xxxxxx.it | Select-Object OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy, UserPrincipalName
OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy UserPrincipalName
------------------------ -----------------
DK1002                   bruger2@xxxxxx.it


PS C:\Users\jkj> Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity "bruger2@xxxxxx.it" -PolicyName $Null -WarningVariable Warn -ErrorVariable ErrorVar -Verbose
PS C:\Users\jkj> Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity bruger2@xxxxxx.it | Select-Object OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy, UserPrincipalName
OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy UserPrincipalName
------------------------ -----------------
DK1002                   bruger2@xxxxxx.it


PS C:\Users\jkj> $Warn
PS C:\Users\jkj> $ErrorVar
PS C:\Users\jkj>
```

I have also attempted to do it by forcing the deletion of the VoiceRoutingPolicy. This was done on a different user and policy.

I was able to delete the VoiceRoutingPolicy, but the user still has a policy "100000001" assigned and prints a warning when getting the user:

```
PS C:\Users\jkj> Remove-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity DK -Force
PS C:\Users\jkj> Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity bruger1@xxxxxx.it | Select-Object OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy, UserPrincipalName
WARNING: "OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy" with identity "1000000001" assigned to "sip:bruger1@xxxxxx.it" has been removed from configuration store.

OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy UserPrincipalName
------------------------ -----------------
1000000001               bruger1@xxxxxx.it


PS C:\Users\jkj>
```

So i have yet to successfully be able to remove the VoiceRoutingPolicy from a user.

Have anyone had success with removing a VoiceRoutingPolicy from a CsOnlineUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to a  contact i have who works with Microsoft Teams and Skype for Business Online. He told me it usually takes effects pretty shortly after running the commands, but that i might have hit a replication issue. If that is the case, it can take up to 4 hours to complete according to his estimation.

I tried leaving it overnight, and now all my users have successfully had their VoiceRoutingPolicies removed:

```
PS C:\Git\teams-powershell> Get-CsOnlineUser | Select-Object OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy, UserPrincipalName

OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy UserPrincipalName
------------------------ -----------------
                         3428fcbdec774fbc80d797dd1d1ff408test3041@3041.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.dk
                         7388bb0a1b104d63ac7b2028bc3dccb4test@xxxxxx.xxxxxx.dk
                         bruger2@xxxxxx.it
                         bruger3@xxxxxx.it
                         bruger4@xxxxxx.it
                         bruger1@xxxxxx.it
                         admin@xxxxxx.it


PS C:\Git\teams-powershell>
```

For my script i won't have the luxury of waiting up to 4 hours, so my workaround will be to forcefully delete the policy, and then setting all the users to `$Null` which should then take effect sometime after.

So, something like this as an example:

```
Remove-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity DK -Force
Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity "bruger1@xxxxxx.it" -PolicyName $Null
Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity "bruger2@xxxxxx.it" -PolicyName $Null
Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity "bruger3@xxxxxx.it" -PolicyName $Null
Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity "bruger4@xxxxxx.it" -PolicyName $Null
```